# MySQL, join vs string parsing

Tags: python, mysql, json, sqlalchemy, performance-testing

I should first put a warning that this can be a little longer question. So please bear with me. One of my projects (That I started very recently) had a table which looked like this

```
name (varchar)
scores (text)
```

Example value is like this -

```
['AAA', '[{"score": 3.0, "subject": "Algebra"}, {"score": 5.0, "subject": "geography"}]']
```

As you can see the second field is the string representation of a JSON array.

In good faith, I redesigned this table into the following two tables

```
table-name:
id - Int, auto_inc, primary_key
name - varchar

table-scores:
id - int, auto_inc, primary_key
subject - varchar
score- float
name - int, FK to table-name
```

I have this following code in my python file to represent the tables (At this point, I assume that you are familiar with Python and SqlAlchemy, and so I will skip the specific imports and all to make it shorter)

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Name(Base):
    __tabelname__ = "name_table"
    id  = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255), index=True)

class Score(Base):
    __tablename__ = "score_table"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject = Column(String(255), index=True)
    score = Column(Float)
    name = Column(ForeignKey('Name.id'), nullable=False, index=True)

    Name = relationship(u'Name')
```

The first table has ~ 778284 rows whereas the second table has ~ 907214 rows.

After declaring them and populating them using the initial data I went to make an experiment. The goal - To find all the subjects whose score is > 5.0 for a given name. (Here, for a second, please consider that name is unique across the DB), and then run the same process 100 times and then take the average to find out how long this query is taking. Following is what I am doing (Please imagine and session is a valid db session I obtained before calling this function.)

```
def test_time():
    for i in range(0, 100):
        scores = session.query(Score, Name.name).join(Name).filter(Name.name=='AAA').filter(Score.score>5.0).all()
        array = []        
        for score in scores:
            array.append((score[0].subject, score[0].score))
```

I am not doing anything with the array I am creating. But I am calling this function which runs this query 100 times and I am using `default_timer` from `timeit` to measure the time elapsed. Following is the result for three runs -

```
Avarage -  0.10969632864
Avarage -  0.105748419762
Avarage -  0.105768380165
```

Now, as I was curious, so what I did is that I created another quick and dirty python file and declared this following class there -

```
class DirtyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "dirty_table"
    name = Column(String(255), primary_key=True)
    scores = Column(Text)
```

And then I created the following function to achieve the same goal but this time reading the data from the second field, parse it back to python dict, run a for loop over all the elements of the list, add in the array only those elements whose score value is > 5.0. Here it goes -

```
def dirty_timer():
    for i in range(0,100):
        scores = session.query(DirtyTable).filter_by(name='AAA').all()
        for score in scores:
             x = json.loads(score.scores)
             array = []
             for member in x:
                 if x['score'] > 5.0:
                     array.append((x['subject'], x['score']))
```

This is the time of three runs -

```
Avarage -  0.0288228917122
Avarage -  0.0296836185455
Avarage -  0.0298663306236
```

Am I missing something? Normalizing the DB (I believe this is all what I tried to do by breaking the original table in two tables) gave me worse result. How is that possible. What is wrong with my approach?

Please let me know your thoughts. Sorry for the long post but had to explain everything properly.

Comment: The join has a computational cost, i am not suprised that it takes longer. As matter of fact in OLAP databases is common to denormalize to speed us queries having all data in one table.

Comment: This is an useful comment. Thank you sir :) I kind of understand a little bit better the cause now.

Comment: You are welcome! If you like my answer please up-vote the comment!!!